# .Net TimezoneInfo.ConvertTime UTC date to Samoa incorrect value returned

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

`var finalValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(x, timeZoneInfo).ToString(format);`[image][image]
[image]
[image]

When applying the ConvertTime method to my 'x' date which is in UTC to the Samoa Standard Time it's incorrectly applying +14 hours instead of the +13 hours that is showing on the BaseUtcOffset in the timeZoneInfo , my 'finalValue' var should match 03:14:39 and not 04:14:39, this method is working correctly for other timezones though

Comment: It is due to your PC timezone settings.  The final time is using your PC settings to display the time.  Probably you settings is in Daylight savings time which is adding the hour.

Comment: According with the ConvertTime Method if the parameter 'x' has the Kind property set to UTC it should return the value to match the difference from UTC to Samoa time, and not apply any local conversions, or am I missing something? all other timezones seem to work correctly, are you able to run a sample on your machine to validate that this Timezone is converting to the Samoa time that matches google Samoa time now?

Comment: You are converting to UTC, but then output with ToString().  The ToString() is using you local PC setting to convert a DateTime to a string. The Convert is creating a DateTime object.

Comment: DataTime stores the value as a number which is the number of ticks (100 ns) from 1/1/01.  When you use ToString a conversion is performed and outputs a string in local time.

Comment: @jdweng - That's incorrect.  `DateTime.ToString` doesn't apply any conversions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This indeed appears to be a bug, due to missing data in the Windows registry related to the 2021 change to DST rules in Samoa.

https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/samoa-removes-dst.html

This was implemented in [IANA 2021b](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2021-September/000066.html), but it appears Microsoft missed it.  It's not on the [Microsoft DST blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/daylight-saving-time-time-zone/bg-p/DSTBlog).

A cleaner repoduction:

```cs
var dto1 = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z");
Console.WriteLine(dto1.ToString("o"));

TimeZoneInfo tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Samoa Standard Time");
var dto2 = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dto1, tz);
Console.WriteLine(dto2.ToString("o"));
```

Output:

```
2022-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+00:00
2022-01-01T14:00:00.0000000+14:00
```

(The last one should be `2022-01-01T13:00:00.0000000+13:00`.)

The relevant Windows Registry key is:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Samoa Standard Time\Dynamic DST` which on my (fully updated Win 11 22H2) machine shows:

[image: screenshot of registry editor]

The 2012 entry is being applied for all years.  There should have been a new entry for 2021 ending DST but not restarting it, and another entry for 2022 that doesn't have DST at all.

I'll report this to Microsoft.  Thanks!